# Most similar character between Brawl and Ultimate

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate, super-smash-bros-brawl

I'd like to get some practice on Super Smash Bros. Brawl on the Wii version so the next time I play Ultimate I should hopefully do better.  What characters are the most similar in Ultimate to their respective Brawl versions, and would be best to practice with (not Sonic, as he's too annoying)?

Comment: What level of play are you practicing for? Do you just want the moves to be similar? Or the combos and tech as well? The physics and tech of the games are very different (in Ultimate you can cancel your dash with any grounded move for example while brawl has DACUS and trips), so depending on your level, practicing in one game can hurt you when you play the other.

Comment: I am kind of new to both games (just got brawl not that long ago) so my level is pretty low.  I've noticed that most characters special moves are similar, but some of them feel pretty different, for instance fox's blaster bolts are quite different, and meta knight is nerfed.  So Ultimate doesn't have dash attacks?  I'd heard about the trips not being in ultimate.  I guess I mostly want to figure out some more basic mechanics such as parrying.

Comment: I just figured it would be better if I used a character that feels similar in both games.  As you can probably tell, I don't know much about the differences between the games. =)

Comment: Just looked up some stuff, so yeah combos are going to be really different, so I guess I should mostly go for characters whos playstyles are very similar in both games, aside from combos as they are significantly reduced in brawl.

Comment: @Millard Ultimate has dash attacks, but not the "Dash Attack Canceled Up Smash". A combo that I remember making Snake very powerful.

Comment: This question isn't opinion based, it's based off stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your response to the comments, I would say the answer is "whoever you feel most interested/comfortable with". Most characters are very similar or only have a few new moves, so for just learning the basics of Smash any character should be ok.

A lot of skills are transferable between these two games, even if the details of general mechanics differ quite a lot. There are major differences in some specific situations, but I doubt they will come across as important unless you're relatively experienced in Smash.

Some characters have more substantial changes between Brawl and Ultimate, mostly due to reworks done in Smash 4. These include for example Link, Diddy Kong, Zelda, Meta Knight, Falco, Yoshi, Ice Climbers, Sonic, Bowser, R.O.B., and Olimar.

For learning the game I also don't have any specific recommendation. Each character has its strengths and weaknesses, and you'll find out about them as you improve. Some people feel that characters with multiple mid-air jumps are easier to control at first, but it's ultimately down to preference.

Combos are quite different between Brawl and Ultimate, but outside of tournament play they rarely are the deciding factor of matches.

Comment: Ok, thnx for the advice! I'm probably gonna work on some characters like Pikachu, and also Ike, cause I want to try some of the sword characters.  Maybe Ganandorf too.  Anyway, thnx!

Comment: Oh cool!  Pikachu is listed as a great counter against both Pit and Joker, which were the characters I was playing against the most.  Of course, games are determined mostly by skill, so it doesnt matter that much.

Comment: Nice! If you're interested in Pikachu, I recommend watching Esam's match videos for both games. He is one of the greatest and smartest Pikachu players of all time.

Comment: Thanks!  I just love raining my lightning bolt down on their heads!  PIKAAA!